# ThinkPad T14 AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 4750U suspend resume fail at GPU?

Tags: 20.04, suspend, amdgpu

The computer fail to resume after suspend in latest kernel 5.9.1:
Linux kever-T14 5.9.1-050901-generic #202010170731 SMP Sat Oct 17 07:42:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here is the fail log, seems like GPU issue:

```
Oct 29 09:43:22 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.116286] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Oct 29 09:43:22 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.128894] Filesystems sync: 0.012 seconds
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.260585] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.264068] OOM killer disabled.
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.264069] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.265619] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.586043] [drm] free PSP TMR buffer
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.634200] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.686830] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.750698] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.750702] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.751035] xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: Zeroing 64bit base registers, expecting fault
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.751165] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.751205] [drm] PSP is resuming...
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2207.771099] [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf41f800000 for PSP TMR
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.094295] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.094976] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.095870] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.118684] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.340880] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341306] gmc_v9_0_process_interrupt: 4 callbacks suppressed
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341312] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341315] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106000000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341316] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341318] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341319] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341320] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341322] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341323] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341324] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341331] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341332] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106001000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341334] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341335] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341336] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341338] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341339] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341340] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341341] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341346] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341347] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106003000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341349] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341350] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341351] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341352] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341353] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341355] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341356] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341360] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341362] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106005000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341363] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341364] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341365] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341367] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341368] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341369] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341370] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341375] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341376] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106006000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341377] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341379] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341380] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341381] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341382] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341383] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341385] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341389] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341391] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106004000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341392] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341393] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341394] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341395] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341397] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341398] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341399] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341403] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341405] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106007000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341406] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341407] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341408] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341409] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341411] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341412] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341413] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341418] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341419] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106870000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341421] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341422] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341423] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341424] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341425] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341427] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341428] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341436] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341437] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106002000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341439] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341440] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341441] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341442] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341443] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341445] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341446] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341451] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32770, for process Xorg pid 997 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1047)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341453] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800106009000 from client 27
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341454] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341455] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341456] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341458] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341459] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341460] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.341461] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu:    RW: 0x0
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.587950] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4694]
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.628197] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1162..]
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.689528] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx test failed (-110)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.689645] [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.689761] [drm:amdgpu_device_resume [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu_device_ip_resume failed (-110).
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.689958] PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_resume+0x0/0xf0 returns -110
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.689966] PM: Device 0000:07:00.0 failed to resume async: error -110
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.691121] OOM killer enabled.
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.691123] Restarting tasks ... done.
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.694087] thermal thermal_zone0: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.705465] PM: suspend exit
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.762400] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-200:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-200:00, irq=IGNORE)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.886463] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: Link is Down
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2208.914438] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-500:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-500:00, irq=IGNORE)
Oct 29 10:09:50 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2209.114397] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
Oct 29 10:09:53 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2212.180669] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Oct 29 10:09:53 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2212.180705] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926683] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring sdma0 timeout, signaled seq=47411, emitted seq=47413
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926842] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process  pid 0 thread  pid 0
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926853] amdgpu 0000:07:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926883] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926884] kernel BUG at mm/slub.c:304!
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926898] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926903] CPU: 3 PID: 188 Comm: kworker/3:1 Tainted: G        W         5.9.1-050901-generic #202010170731
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926905] Hardware name: LENOVO 20UD0004CD/20UD0004CD, BIOS XXXXXXXX(1.05 ) 06/11/2020
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926914] Workqueue: events drm_sched_job_timedout [gpu_sched]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926924] RIP: 0010:__slab_free+0x1f8/0x340
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926928] Code: 44 24 20 e8 2a fc ff ff 44 8b 44 24 20 85 c0 0f 85 4a fe ff ff eb c6 41 f7 46 08 00 0d 21 00 0f 85 2c ff ff ff e9 1e ff ff ff <0f> 0b 80 4c 24 5b 80 45 31 c9 e9 8b fe ff ff ba 01 00 00 00 4c 89
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926931] RSP: 0018:ffffb1d7405f3bc0 EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926934] RAX: ffff91db158e6500 RBX: 000000008020001c RCX: ffff91db158e6400
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926936] RDX: ffff91db158e6400 RSI: ffffd27acf563900 RDI: ffff91db3dc43600
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926937] RBP: ffffb1d7405f3c58 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: ffffffffc1370cde
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926939] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffd27acf563900
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926940] R13: ffff91db158e6400 R14: ffff91db3dc43600 R15: ffff91db158e6400
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926944] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff91db3f8c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926945] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926947] CR2: 00007fb3f54f3cb8 CR3: 00000001a320e000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.926949] Call Trace:
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927096]  ? uninit_queue+0xe/0x10 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927100]  kfree+0x217/0x230
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927234]  uninit_queue+0xe/0x10 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927366]  kq_uninitialize+0x83/0xf0 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927496]  kernel_queue_uninit+0x17/0x30 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927624]  pm_uninit+0x16/0x20 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927754]  stop_cpsch+0xa7/0xd0 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.927883]  kgd2kfd_suspend.part.0+0x35/0x50 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928011]  kgd2kfd_pre_reset+0x3c/0x50 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928138]  amdgpu_amdkfd_pre_reset+0x1a/0x20 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928308]  amdgpu_device_gpu_recover.cold+0x1e8/0x67a [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928452]  amdgpu_job_timedout+0x118/0x140 [amdgpu]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928457]  drm_sched_job_timedout+0x6b/0xf0 [gpu_sched]
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928465]  process_one_work+0x1e8/0x3b0
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928468]  worker_thread+0x50/0x370
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928472]  kthread+0x12f/0x150
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928475]  ? process_one_work+0x3b0/0x3b0
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928477]  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x70/0x70
Oct 29 10:10:00 kever-T14 kernel: [ 2218.928483]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
```

Comment: Hi, I seem to have a very similar issue. GPU-related errors after resume, on a Ryzen 7 PRO. Any progress since?